# Why does running the program with cargo run result in an error saying Command target/debug/depot not found?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

So I decided to make a project in Rust, and if your wondering what it is, its basically a package manager for static websites. It was all good until I used `cargo run` and all of a sudden it just stops working. Instead of working, the program throws an error that states: `ERROR: Command target/debug/depot not found`. I'm smart enough to know that this relates to the binary that cargo runs after completing the build process of the `cargo run` command. So, I went to the `target/debug` directory and saw that the depot binary actually exists, which is really weird, because cargo should've found it. After all, it was searching for the exact directory the binary was in.

I tried using `ls` on it, but the command found it. I ran file on the binary and used `grep` to find the part where it said it was an executable, and sure enough, `grep` found it, meaning that the file is executable. Just for good measure, I tried using `chmod` to change the permissions of the binary, but it still didn't work.

For your information, I was running `cargo run` in the root directory of my project, and this is my Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "depot"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ansi_term = "0.12.1"
tiny_http = "0.12.0"
```

If you need more information, kindly ask me for it, because I'm really stumped at this error message. Thank you for reading this and I hope I get an answer the next day (in my time, of course).

Comment: If the executable is there you can try to launch it directly `./target/debug/depot` to se if any error is produced.

Comment: `cargo clean` and build it again

Comment: It'd be easier if you'd share your `cargo.toml` also if you have any build scripts  and the current directory which used for running `cargo run`